# Programing against an ever changing XML schema

Tags: xml, reflection, xsd, schema

You have an xml schema, which you run through the XML Schema Definition Tool (xsd.exe) to auto generate your classes.  You can then programme against that to populate the classes / serialise to an XML document / validate against the original XML schema… all great.

But what happens if that xml Schema changes every week. I do not want to keep on going in and making code changes every time a new version of the schema is released.  Is there a general technique in dealing with this type of problem?

I had thought about analysing the schema, and producing a ‘mapping class’ which will allow end users to map new properties found within the schema to columns within the database.  But then creating a method to loop through this, and use reflection to map the data onto the auto generated classes is difficult with large schemas.

Answer (score 0):

Data binding only works well when you have a stable schema. If the schema is changing frequently, use a different technology, unless you want to tear your hair out. Native XML languages such as XSLT and XQuery handle this kind of flexibility far better than compiled languages like Java and C#; if you must use Java, then use a tree model such as JDOM rather than using data binding to Java classes.

You mention a database: again, if you want to handle change easily, the best thing is to keep the data in XML end-to-end, by using an XML processing language and an XML database.